# Adding multi language support to a SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I currently have a database with Latin collation and therefore isn't accepting other characters (e.g. Arabic). Is there a way to modify the current database to support Arabic characters?

I've also tried creating a new database with Arabic collation and then importing the tables and data from the original but I was still missing triggers and indexes.

Comment: to modify the collation you have to drop all indexes, foreign keys, primary keys and then rebuild them once done. your best bet is to build a new database using the original scripts with the correct collation and then import the data. if you miss the scripts it is the moment to create them...